# Detect if javascript is compressed with YIU compressor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, tostring, detect, yui-compressor

I have made a construction to defer loading javascript to speed up page loading. To deploy websites i use the YIU compressor to minimize the scripts, also for speed. There will be two versions of the scripts, one is compressed and orginal one is not. For example: example-min.js and example.js. Some javascripts will be loaded only when a functionality comes in and sometimes it needs more scripts (plugin idea).

Anyway, i want to know (if other js files are needed) if the 'host' js file is compressed, so when it is compressed it loads the minified version of the js file. If not (when developing) it loads the orginial file.

For example:

```
function myObject()
{
var o = this;

o.isJsMinified = function()
{ s =  o.isJsMinified.toString(),ss='s=  '; 
  return (s.indexOf(ss+'o.is')<0);
};

o.require = function( s, delay, baSync, fCallback ) // add script to dom
{
 var oo = document.createElement('script'),
 oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
 f = (typeof fCallback == 'function')?fCallback:function(){};
 if( !oHead )
  { return false; }
 oo.onload = function() {oo.id='loaded'; f(oo); };
 oo.type = 'text/javascript';
 oo.async = (typeof baSync == 'boolean')?baSync:false;
 oo.src = s;
 setTimeout( function() { oHead.appendChild(oo); }, (typeof delay != 'number')?delay:1 );  
 return true;
};

.....
.....

if( <new functionality found> )
{
  if( o.isJsMinified() )
   { o.require('new-min.js',800); }
  else { o.require('new.js',800); }
}

.....
.....

}
```

When you look at the jsIsMinified() function i use a trick to detect if the function itself (the source) is stripped from spaces (minified version). But, there is a problem with firefox, it does not return the original formatting so it cannot detect any difference.

For example:
// compressed by YUI compressor:

```
o.isJsMinified=function(){s=o.isJsMinified.toString(),ss='s=  ';return (s.indexOf(ss+'o.is')<0);};
```

Firefox will display:

```
function () {
    s = o.isJsMinified.toString(), ss = "s= ";
    return s.indexOf(ss + "o.is") < 0;
}
```

The function fails in firefox, it always 'says' it is not compressed. Does anybody know a work-around for this?

Comment: Why for gs downvote someone this closed topic?

Comment: Do not deface your questions, particularly ones with existing answers. I've rolled back your edits here, but please don't do that again.

Answer (score 1):

I really think you overcomplicate things here. Woah, why don't you just create two folders on your server like `js/production` and `js/debug`. You might have one flag within your javascript files that could indicate whether or not it's productive or debug. Like

```
if( window.DEBUG ) {
    o.require('/js/debug/new.js',800);
}
else {
    o.require('/js/production/new.js',800);
}
```

thinking about that, even those folders are unnecessary. You can just distinguish between `.min` or not. The only thing you really need to do is to set a global `DEBUG` variable in your code.

Comment: i am not overcomplicate things, maybe in the example i show i will. I understand what you are saying. But i don't want to flag things with debug or something.

Comment: @Erwinus: the problem is, you can't reliably determine whether or not a script file was compressed or not. I mean, of course you can try to spot things which are very typicall for a compressed file, or even watchout for some kind of "comment" a compressor leaves in the file, but pretty pretty unreliable.

Comment: Also it is working great in other browsers. The problem is firefox. Function.toString() returns formatted text instead of 'as-is'.

Comment: Why it is unreliable? I always use the same compressor and with the same results. You cannot use comments because it will be stripped amd that is not what i try to compare.

Comment: And in no case it will fail except that it will load the uncompressed file.

Comment: Also when you use the debug thing you describe, all scripts are minified or not so it is difficult to 'play'/test other cases. That is what i hate about flagging things. It is difficult to maintain.

Comment: @Erwinus: try `.toSource()` instead of `.toString()` in FF then.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't help. When i specify s='test'; in the function the output will be shown as s = 'test;, it still formats the source.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP headers will specify whether compression was requested and enabled, but [there's no easy way to read them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript) so you might want a special Firefox extension for development.

Perhaps the right place to make the change is in the server, send the non-minified script out if a certain header is given (and the requestor IP address is local).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the case. You are talking about gzip compression.